# Initializing bool variable

Tags: c#

I just wondering which way is more preferable to initialize bool variable.

For example I need to parse some value into boolean.

```
bool.TryParse(stringVar, out boolVar);
```

Before this I need to initialize boolVar. 
Which one is more proper:

```
bool boolVar;
```

or

```
var boolVar = false;
```

as by default bool value is `false`.

Comment: There's not difference. It's personal preference. If you ask me I'd write `var foo = default(bool);` but not everyone agrees with that. Who cares ;-P I like `var` so I would never write `bool foo;` ;-]

Answer (score 2):

C#7 introduces [Out variables](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/03/09/new-features-in-c-7-0/) so you can write the following:

```
bool.TryParse("true", out bool result);
```